# Launch a react app (bundled with webpack) into a react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react app bundled with webpack 4 into a file (bundle.js) and i want to launch it into another react app as a component.

```
import Component from '../../../build/bundle'

const AcomponentWithBundle = () => (
  <div>
    <Component />
  </div>
);
```

This of course is not working

Here is the error message :

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I understand the error message because in the bundle i have no export, but i need to be able to do that and have no clue how to do it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Check how others React packages are created, and do the same so that you can reuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual practice is to create a NPM package and define a prepack script to transpile your React component with Babel, and then either publish, pack or link it with `npm` so that you can `npm install` it in your app.

Webpack should be used as the last step of your whole build process to produce a full app to run in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In React component-based philosophy the only allowed pattern, in this case, are:

- redirect to the other app, without pretend to *embed it*
- load needed component from the other app without embed the full app

As workaround (in order to keep dom, routing etc etc) you can load *other app* in a